# How to create a nested list in reStructuredText?

Tags: markup, restructuredtext, python-sphinx

I am trying to create a properly nested list using the following code (following [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/latest/rest.html#lists-and-quote-like-blocks) and [docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html) docs):

```
1. X

  a. U
  b. V
  c. W

2. Y
3. Z
```

I expect this to result in two `OL`s but I get the following output instead:

```
<ol class="arabic simple"> 
  <li>X</li> 
</ol> 

<blockquote> 
  <div>
    <ol class="loweralpha simple"> 
      <li>U</li> 
      <li>V</li> 
      <li>W</li> 
    </ol> 
  </div>
</blockquote> 

<ol class="arabic simple" start="2"> 
  <li>Y</li> 
  <li>Z</li> 
</ol>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to get the following result?

```
<ol class="arabic simple"> 
  <li>X
    <ol class="loweralpha simple"> 
      <li>U</li> 
      <li>V</li> 
      <li>W</li> 
    </ol> 
  </li>
  <li>Y</li> 
  <li>Z</li> 
</ol>
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Make sure the nested list is indented to the same level as the text of the parent list (or three characters, whichever is greater), like this:

```
1. X

   a. U
   b. V
   c. W

2. Y
3. Z
```

Then you'll get the output you expected.

Comment: It appears that this is not exactly correct. In my case I was using `*` as the list indicator and when I indented my next line the two characters needed to line up with the text of the parent list, my list was treated as a separate list inside of a blockquote. The empirical rule I've found is that the inner list must be *indented at least three characters*.

Comment: @Akrikos Thanks! I updated the answer to include that caveat.

Comment: Indenting the inner list with 3 spaces didn’t work for me when using `*` lists. I think the answer was right the first time.

Answer (score 45):

If you want Sphinx to take care of the numbering for you, do this.

```
#. X
#. Y

   #. u 
   #. v 

#. Z
```

Comment: Just re-highlighting this detail since it still applies: u and v must be indented at least 3 spaces (not 2 spaces), to match the text of the parent level. Otherwise, you'll get "1. Z" instead of "3. Z".

Comment: @S.Kirby It also seems that one must indent more, if one uses a list item like `iii.`, which uses more places. It seems text has to be aligned and there seems not to be a specific count of spaces one can use for all cases.

Comment: Please note that the extra empty lines are also important here. So you will need 3 spaces for each element of the nested sub list, and above and below an empty line.

Comment: The important point is the indentation of the preceding item *text*. This may be less than 3 if the text starts on the line following the list marker.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the indentation of the nested list, you can adjust the containing list item's indentation to match it. To get an indentation less than 3 spaces, start the item text on the line after the list marker (the whitespace after the list marker may include a newline character).

```
1. 
  X

  a. U
  b. V
  c. W

2. Y
3. Z
```

This is tested with Docutils and should work with Sphinx, too. Other implementations may show different results.