# Sphinx: Resume list numbering after a note section

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, continuation, numbered-list

Consider the following list in [ReStructuredText](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText):

```
Broken list example
-------------------

#. First do spam
#. Then do ``eggs``

  .. note::

    Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisistion

#. The list restarts after the note
```

When the list is compiled in [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/index.html), the number after the note are reset to `1`:

[image: List number restart result screenshot]

Any idea how to continue the numbered list after a `note` section?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The discontinuity of the list is caused by the `note` being a standalone element, not a child of the second numbered list element. To prevent the discontinuity of the list, start the `note` directive at the same indentation (in this case, 3 spaces) as the the text of the intended parent numbered list element. So instead of your sample reStructuredText, try this:

```
Fixed list example
------------------

#. First do spam
#. Then do ``eggs``

   .. note::

      Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisistion

#. Then do spam and ``eggs``.
```

This is one of those things about reStructuredText that's neither easy to spot, nor particularly well documented; see [this question on nested lists for a closely-related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550089/how-to-create-a-nested-list-in-restructuredtext).

Comment: And what would you do, if you want to include a note under a code section? If I indent it to the same level as the code, it will include it in the code block instead of it's own block.

Comment: @ÖzerS. I'm not sure what you mean, so you might need to start a new question to illustrate the problem more clearly.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332502/sphinx-note-block-in-a-list-under-a-code-block