# Sphinx document: Continue numbered list after a code block

Tags: syntax-highlighting, python-sphinx, numbered-list

Consider the following list in [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/):

```
#. List item 1
#. List item 2

.. code-block:: Objective-C

    Blah1.framework
    Blah2.framework
    libfoo.dylib
    libbar.dylib
#. List item 3
#. ...
```

The list numbering is reset after the code block, so I an html with:

```
1. List item 1
2. List item 2

    Blah1.framework
    Blah2.framework
    libfoo.dylib
    libbar.dylib

1. List item 3    <--- Numbering is reset to 1
2. ...
```

Is there a way to continue the list numbering after a code block?

Comment: What about this answer given to a similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29371701/407651